# DirectX 9 Present (render) video frame to specific location to HWND leaving existing window contents untouched

Tags: windows, directx, rendering, direct3d

I am trying to do something specific using the DirectX 9 APIs in my application.

When I setup the directx device it requires a window handle (HWND) which ultimately the graphics driver ends up knowing about and using. What I am trying to do is inside the given window handle just have the graphics driver render to ONLY a specific portion of the window and leave the rest of the window untouched. For example. Let's say my window size is 1280x720 and I only want the video frame to render and present to a location inside the window of say 300x200. What is the best way using the directx 9 API to do this. I have the device all setup and I can already render video just fine to the entire window, but I am trying now to render to a window handle that already contains contents and specifies to me where I should render my video frame on the same window. I notice that event if I specify to present to that location it blacks out the entire window along with displaying my frame when I make the call to PresentEx().

I am wondering if there is a way to tell the graphics driver NOT to black out everything else in that window? Initially this window has some HTML elements created and I am trying to not have the driver clobber the rest of the window.

I thought about somehow having the entire back buffer present to the window but somehow making a portion of the buffer where I don't want to draw to transparent, but I do not konw how to achieve this either. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Rather than messing around with viewports, it's probably better to create a child window for your DX content and let it have the whole thing (assuming you intend to restrict it to a rectangular area).

Comment: Why do you think it might be better not to mess around with viewports? I am not familiar with viewports, but could that be an option?

Comment: In my opinion, I would take the simple option - create a child window at a fixed position in your main content window and dedicate that to DirectX. Mixing graphics output from different libraries is possible but messy and will inevitably end in tears. If you *really* want to know about viewports - [read this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb206341(v=vs.85).aspx) and see what you think.

Comment: Unfortunately using a child window is not possible in my solution. I am not sure viewports will solve my issues since it seems like they limit presenting to within the backbuffer? I can actually force the backbuffer to only render to a certain location in the window (I verified this by coloring the backbuffer), the problem i am having is the first call to PresentEx something (maybe DX runtime) paints the entire window surface black.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was a side effect of calling DwmSetPresentParameters on the window Desktop Windows manager. This was in Windows 8 since windows 8.1 deprecates calling this function. So however DirectX works with DWM after calling the DwmSetPresentParameters function causes the entire window to blacked out.